# Do there exists $p$ and $q$ primes for which $p^3+1=2q^2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Do there exists $p$ and $q$ primes for which
$p^3+1=2q^2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer**:

No

**Proof**:

First we shall prove that $p=2$ can't be a solution.

If $p=2$ then we need to find a prime $q$ such that $9=2^3+1=2q^2$, obviously there is no such prime.

Now let us assume that there are prime solutions, we will call them $(p,q)$, therefore:
$$(p+1)(p^2-p+1)=p^3+1=2q^2$$
Therefore
$$\frac{p+1}{2}(p^2-p+1)\mid q^2$$
where $\frac{p+1}{2}\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ since $p$ is an odd prime.

Now let's assume that $p^2-p+1 = 1$.

In this case we get no prime solutions because the solutions to $p^2-p= 0$ are $1$ and $0$ both are not prime.

Therefore because both of the factors are in $\mathbb{N} \setminus\{1\}$ and their product divide $q^2$ where $q$ is a prime number we get:
$$\frac{p+1}{2}=q \  \land \ p^2-p+1 = q \ \Rightarrow \ p^2-p+1 = \frac{p+1}{2} \ \Rightarrow \ 2p^2-3p+1 = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ p=1 \lor p=\frac{1}{2}$$
And again we get that $p$ be is not a prime resulting in a contradiction to the assumption that there are solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are two prime numbers satisfying
$$p^3+1=2q^2.$$
Note that
$$p^3+1=(p+1)(p^2-p+1),$$
and let $d$ denote the greatest common divisor of these two factors. Then $d$ divides $3$ because
$$1\cdot(p^2-p+1)-(p-2)\cdot(p+1)=3.$$
If $d=1$ then either $p+1\leq2$ or $p^2-p+1\leq2$, both of which are clearly impossible.

If $d=3$ then $3^2$ divides $p^3+1=2q^2$ and so $q=3$. But then
$$p^3+1=2q^2=18,$$
which is again clearly impossible.